# Retrofit & CheckWX.com Response

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I have an issue in that I need to parse multiple object type responses from the CheckWX.com API. (see https://api.checkwx.com/). At the moment I have the `ScalarsConverterFactory` and the `GSONConverterFactory` in my code. My Gson converter works fine with no errors. However, when I get an error, parsing seems to fail and onFailure is called. I need to report all successful stations as well as those that failed. How can I handle this in Retrofit?

Here is the response for a single station request error:

```
{
   "results":1,
   "data":[
      "KNZL Invalid Station ICAO"
   ]
}
```

Here is the response for a station request without error:

```
{
   "results":1,
   "data":[
      {
         "icao":"KAJO",
         "name":"Corona Municipal",
         "observed":"03-11-2018 @ 22:56Z",
         "raw_text":"KAJO 032256Z AUTO 28010KT 10SM CLR 31/07 A2991 RMK AO2 SLP135 T03060072 $",
         "barometer":{
            "hg":29.91,
            "kpa":101.29000000000001,
            "mb":1013.5
         },
         "clouds":[
            {
               "code":"CLR",
               "text":"Clear skies",
               "base_feet_agl":0,
               "base_meters_agl":0
            }
         ],
         "dewpoint":{
            "celsius":7,
            "fahrenheit":45
         },
         "elevation":{
            "feet":535,
            "meters":163
         },
         "flight_category":"VFR",
         "humidity_percent":22,
         "temperature":{
            "celsius":31,
            "fahrenheit":88
         },
         "visibility":{
            "miles":"10",
            "meters":"16,093"
         },
         "wind":{
            "degrees":280,
            "speed_kts":10,
            "speed_mph":12,
            "speed_mps":5
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is the response for a single station success and single station error:

```
{
   "results":2,
   "data":[
      {
         "icao":"KAJO",
         "name":"Corona Municipal",
         "observed":"03-11-2018 @ 22:56Z",
         "raw_text":"KAJO 032256Z AUTO 28010KT 10SM CLR 31/07 A2991 RMK AO2 SLP135 T03060072 $",
         "barometer":{
            "hg":29.91,
            "kpa":101.29000000000001,
            "mb":1013.5
         },
         "clouds":[
            {
               "code":"CLR",
               "text":"Clear skies",
               "base_feet_agl":0,
               "base_meters_agl":0
            }
         ],
         "dewpoint":{
            "celsius":7,
            "fahrenheit":45
         },
         "elevation":{
            "feet":535,
            "meters":163
         },
         "flight_category":"VFR",
         "humidity_percent":22,
         "temperature":{
            "celsius":31,
            "fahrenheit":88
         },
         "visibility":{
            "miles":"10",
            "meters":"16,093"
         },
         "wind":{
            "degrees":280,
            "speed_kts":10,
            "speed_mph":12,
            "speed_mps":5
         }
      },
      "CYPG METAR Currently Unavailable"
   ]
}
```

And here is the response for multiple station successes and errors:

```
{
   "results":5,
   "data":[
      {
         "icao":"KAJO",
         "name":"Corona Municipal",
         "observed":"03-11-2018 @ 22:56Z",
         "raw_text":"KAJO 032256Z AUTO 28010KT 10SM CLR 31/07 A2991 RMK AO2 SLP135 T03060072 $",
         "barometer":{
            "hg":29.91,
            "kpa":101.29000000000001,
            "mb":1013.5
         },
         "clouds":[
            {
               "code":"CLR",
               "text":"Clear skies",
               "base_feet_agl":0,
               "base_meters_agl":0
            }
         ],
         "dewpoint":{
            "celsius":7,
            "fahrenheit":45
         },
         "elevation":{
            "feet":535,
            "meters":163
         },
         "flight_category":"VFR",
         "humidity_percent":22,
         "temperature":{
            "celsius":31,
            "fahrenheit":88
         },
         "visibility":{
            "miles":"10",
            "meters":"16,093"
         },
         "wind":{
            "degrees":280,
            "speed_kts":10,
            "speed_mph":12,
            "speed_mps":5
         }
      },
      {
         "icao":"KBIL",
         "name":"Billings Logan International",
         "observed":"03-11-2018 @ 22:53Z",
         "raw_text":"KBIL 032253Z 25006KT 10SM -RA BKN043 BKN050 OVC120 05/01 A3007 RMK AO2 RAB41 SLP196 P0000 T00500011",
         "barometer":{
            "hg":30.07,
            "kpa":101.83,
            "mb":1019.6
         },
         "ceiling":{
            "code":"BKN",
            "text":"Broken",
            "feet_agl":4300,
            "meters_agl":1310.6400000000001
         },
         "clouds":[
            {
               "code":"BKN",
               "text":"Broken",
               "base_feet_agl":4300,
               "base_meters_agl":1310.6400000000001
            },
            {
               "code":"BKN",
               "text":"Broken",
               "base_feet_agl":5000,
               "base_meters_agl":1524
            },
            {
               "code":"OVC",
               "text":"Overcast",
               "base_feet_agl":12000,
               "base_meters_agl":3657.6000000000004
            }
         ],
         "conditions":[
            {
               "code":"RA",
               "prefix":"-",
               "text":"Light Rain"
            }
         ],
         "dewpoint":{
            "celsius":1,
            "fahrenheit":34
         },
         "elevation":{
            "feet":3579,
            "meters":1091
         },
         "flight_category":"VFR",
         "humidity_percent":76,
         "rain_in":0.0050000000000000001,
         "temperature":{
            "celsius":5,
            "fahrenheit":41
         },
         "visibility":{
            "miles":"10",
            "meters":"16,093"
         },
         "wind":{
            "degrees":250,
            "speed_kts":6,
            "speed_mph":7,
            "speed_mps":3
         }
      },
      {
         "icao":"KSAN",
         "name":"San Diego International",
         "observed":"03-11-2018 @ 22:51Z",
         "raw_text":"KSAN 032251Z 29006KT 10SM FEW004 SCT250 24/16 A2993 RMK AO2 SLP135 T02390156",
         "barometer":{
            "hg":29.93,
            "kpa":101.34999999999999,
            "mb":1013.5
         },
         "clouds":[
            {
               "code":"FEW",
               "text":"Few",
               "base_feet_agl":400,
               "base_meters_agl":121.92
            },
            {
               "code":"SCT",
               "text":"Scattered",
               "base_feet_agl":25000,
               "base_meters_agl":7620
            }
         ],
         "dewpoint":{
            "celsius":16,
            "fahrenheit":61
         },
         "elevation":{
            "feet":39,
            "meters":12
         },
         "flight_category":"VFR",
         "humidity_percent":61,
         "temperature":{
            "celsius":24,
            "fahrenheit":75
         },
         "visibility":{
            "miles":"10",
            "meters":"16,093"
         },
         "wind":{
            "degrees":290,
            "speed_kts":6,
            "speed_mph":7,
            "speed_mps":3
         }
      },
      "CYPG METAR Currently Unavailable",
      "KGNG METAR Currently Unavailable"
   ]
}
```

Here is the code for my retrofit client:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl) 
               .client(getHttpClient())
               .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
               .build();
```

As I said, What I need to know is how to properly parse the error strings in the response: for clarification here is the error:

```
CheckWXApi: onFailure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected 
BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 755 path $.data[1], 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was 
STRING at line 1 column 755 path $.data[1]
2018-11-04 11:55:52.376 25533-25533/us.sensornet.aviationweatherv2 
D/CheckWXApiProxy: onMetarReportFailure: called:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was 
STRING at line 1 column 755 path $.data[1]
Caused BY: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT
but was STRING at line 1 column 755 path $.data[1].
```

The is for the query with one successful station and one error. If you look at the responses provided, you'll see the last one or two objects returned in the data array are strings error messages and not the metar weather object. My issue is in handling these strings properly. Simply adding the ScalarConverterFactory didn't solve this.

Comment: Here is the code for my retrofit client:  retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(getHttpClient())
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Use [edit] button and post the code. Now, I edited your question.

Comment: You said `when I get an error, parsing seems to fail and onFailure is called` can you please [edit] and post error logs here?

Comment: Are you properly managing the response parsing? Try to verify that at first. Then you'll have to implement the login on `Callback::onFailure` to parse `Response::errorBody` returned object.

Comment: I believe I've found the answer: Custom GsonDeserializer. I need to write a custom deserializer for the Gson parser to handle the array containing both strings and metar weather objects.